# C# Webbrowser Onclick Javascript event handling

Tags: c#, javascript, onclick, invokescript

I got this code from HTML:

```
<div id="login-buttons">
    <div id="js_login_button">
        <a href="#" onclick="$('#login_form').submit()" class="login_button">
        <span class="button_left"></span>
        <span class="button_middle">Login</span>
        <span class="button_right"></span>
        </a>
    </div>          
</div>
```

Now I need a C# code to **activate / perform a click** into the webpage (which  is loaded into a **webBrowser**)

```
//webBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("$('#login_form').submit()");
```

This doesn't work for me, I tried and searched a lot but I can't find anything.
I **CANNOT** add a function because It's from a website.

Please help me :)

Note: If you need more information from which website I want to make an auto login system. Just ask :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12252378/capturing-a-form-submit-with-jquery-and-submit

Answer (score 0):

`InvokeScript` executes a function by name, rather than evaluates the code.  Define a function by name that does what you want.

```
<script>
   function foo () {
      $('#login_form').submit()
   };
</script>
```

In the C# code, call the function by name

```
webBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("foo");
```

There's more information on the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/be9zzz62.aspx) which covers how to pass parameters and receive results.

Comment: I have figered it out! Thanks in advance who helped me :)