# Redirecting after form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, redirect

I have a little problem with a form. I can't figure out how to redirect to the "thankyou.html" page after the form is filled and submitted. Now the it keeps returning to "form.html" page. Any help would be greatly appriciated!

```
<body class="application">

<!-- content -->

<section class="main-body">

<div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="row-fluid" id="content">

                    <!-- breadcrumbs -->
<div>
<div class="bootstrap-widget-content" id="yw3"><p class="help">

</p><p class="note">The form</p><form class="well form-horizontal" id="yw0" action="form.html" method="post"><div style="visibility:hidden"><input type="hidden" value="1" name="yform_35d652cf" id="yform_35d652cf" /></div>
<div class="control-group "><label class="control-label required" for="Applicant_firstname">Name <span class="required">*</span></label><div class="controls"><input class="span6" name="Applicant[firstname]" id="Applicant_firstname" type="text" /><span class="help-inline error" id="Applicant_firstname_em_" style="display: none"></span></div></div>
<div class="control-group "><label class="control-label required" for="Applicant_lastname">Last name <span class="required">*</span></label><div class="controls"><input class="span6" name="Applicant[lastname]" id="Applicant_lastname" type="text" /><span class="help-inline error" id="Applicant_lastname_em_" style="display: none"></span></div></div>
<div class="control-group "><label class="control-label required" for="Applicant_email">E-mail <span class="required">*</span></label><div class="controls"><input class="span6" name="Applicant[email]" id="Applicant_email" type="text" /><span class="help-inline error" id="Applicant_email_em_" style="display: none"></span></div></div>
<div class="control-group "><label class="control-label" for="Applicant_phone">Phone</label><div class="controls"><input class="span2" name="Applicant[phone]" id="Applicant_phone" type="text" /><span class="help-inline error" id="Applicant_phone_em_" style="display: none"></span></div></div>
<div class="control-group "><label class="control-label" for="Applicant_address">Adress</label><div class="controls"><input class="span6" name="Applicant[address]" id="Applicant_address" type="text" /><span class="help-inline error" id="Applicant_address_em_" style="display: none"></span></div></div>
<div class="control-group "><label class="control-label" for="Applicant_postcode">Number</label><div class="controls"><input class="span6 postSelect2" name="Applicant[postcode]" id="Applicant_postcode" type="text" /><span class="help-inline error" id="Applicant_postcode_em_" style="display: none"></span></div></div>
<div class="control-group "><label class="control-label" for="Applicant_postoffice">City</label><div class="controls"><input class="span6 postSelect2" name="Applicant[postoffice]" id="Applicant_postoffice" type="text" /><span class="help-inline error" id="Applicant_postoffice_em_" style="display: none"></span></div></div>
<div class="control-group "><label class="control-label" for="Applicant_extrainfo">Message</label><div class="controls"><textarea class="span6" name="Applicant[extrainfo]" id="Applicant_extrainfo"></textarea><span class="help-inline error" id="Applicant_extrainfo_em_" style="display: none"></span></div></div>
<div class="control-group "><label class="control-label" for="Applicant_invoice_preference">Toivottu laskutustapa</label><div class="controls"><select placeholder="Valitse toivottu laskutustapa" class="span4" name="Applicant[invoice_preference]" id="Applicant_invoice_preference">
<option value="">Question</option>
<option value="1" selected="selected">option1</option>
<option value="2">option2</option>
<option value="3">option3</option>
</select><span class="help-inline error" id="Applicant_invoice_preference_em_" style="display: none"></span></div></div>

<div class="form-actions">
<button name="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="yw1" type="submit">Tallenna</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<button name="reset" class="btn" id="yw2" type="reset">Palauta oletusarvot</button>&nbsp;</div>

</form></div></div>
</div>
  </div><!-- content -->

</div>

</section>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery.joyride-2.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
/*<![CDATA[*/

        $('.toggle-hidden').click(function() {

            $('.hidden-area').toggle();

            return false;

        });

        $('.toggle-hidden-2').click(function(event) {

            $('.hidden-area').hide();

            $('.' + $(event.target).data('target')).toggle();

            return false;

        });


jQuery(function($) {
jQuery('body').popover({'selector':'[rel=popover]'});
jQuery('body').tooltip({'selector':'[rel=tooltip]'});
jQuery('#yw0').yiiactiveform({'attributes':[{'id':'Applicant_firstname','inputID':'Applicant_firstname','errorID':'Applicant_firstname_em_','model':'Applicant','name':'Applicant[firstname]','enableAjaxValidation':true,'inputContainer':'div.control-group'},{'id':'Applicant_lastname','inputID':'Applicant_lastname','errorID':'Applicant_lastname_em_','model':'Applicant','name':'Applicant[lastname]','enableAjaxValidation':true,'inputContainer':'div.control-group'},{'id':'Applicant_email','inputID':'Applicant_email','errorID':'Applicant_email_em_','model':'Applicant','name':'Applicant[email]','enableAjaxValidation':true,'inputContainer':'div.control-group'},{'id':'Applicant_phone','inputID':'Applicant_phone','errorID':'Applicant_phone_em_','model':'Applicant','name':'Applicant[phone]','enableAjaxValidation':true,'inputContainer':'div.control-group'},{'id':'Applicant_address','inputID':'Applicant_address','errorID':'Applicant_address_em_','model':'Applicant','name':'Applicant[address]','enableAjaxValidation':true,'inputContainer':'div.control-group'},{'id':'Applicant_postcode','inputID':'Applicant_postcode','errorID':'Applicant_postcode_em_','model':'Applicant','name':'Applicant[postcode]','enableAjaxValidation':true,'inputContainer':'div.control-group'},{'id':'Applicant_postoffice','inputID':'Applicant_postoffice','errorID':'Applicant_postoffice_em_','model':'Applicant','name':'Applicant[postoffice]','enableAjaxValidation':true,'inputContainer':'div.control-group'},{'id':'Applicant_extrainfo','inputID':'Applicant_extrainfo','errorID':'Applicant_extrainfo_em_','model':'Applicant','name':'Applicant[extrainfo]','enableAjaxValidation':true,'inputContainer':'div.control-group'},{'id':'Applicant_invoice_preference','inputID':'Applicant_invoice_preference','errorID':'Applicant_invoice_preference_em_','model':'Applicant','name':'Applicant[invoice_preference]','enableAjaxValidation':true,'inputContainer':'div.control-group'}],'errorCss':'error'});
jQuery('#yw4 .alert').alert();
window.setTimeout(function() { $('.alert').alert('close'); }, 5000);

});
</script>
```

Comment: Are you using any server side language..? To what are you submitting the form..?

Comment: @hardbinger Are you joking? Just change action="form.html" to action="thankyou.html"

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12252378/capturing-a-form-submit-with-jquery-and-submit you will maybe find a solution.

Answer (score 2):

Look at your form action:

```
<form class="well form-horizontal" id="yw0" action="form.html" method="post">
```

Well, what is `form.html`?  Is *this page* `form.html`?  If so, then this page is submitting to itself.  That means it's making a POST request to `form.html`, to include the values from the form.  Unless you're doing anything server-side (and it doesn't look like you are), the standard response for any request to a page is to display that page.

If you want your form to post to a different page, change the `action`:

```
<form class="well form-horizontal" id="yw0" action="thankyou.html" method="post">
```

However, be aware that you still need something *server-side* to handle the actual form post.  By changing the `action` all you're doing is telling the form to make a request to `thankyou.html` instead of `form.html`, which will successfully display the "thank you" page.  But it won't actually do anything with the form values by default.

For that, you'll need some kind of server-side code to accept and process those values.  (There are many options in that regard... PHP, ASP.NET, Java, Ruby, etc., etc.)

Note that in server-side code you would also have a lot more control over the flow of the application.  For example, maybe you want the form-handling logic to be on `form.html` (or `form.php` more likely).  The page can still submit to itself, and then in server-side logic you can perform a redirect to another page.  This can be useful if you want to validate the input and re-display the form on an error, and only redirect to `thankyou.html` if validation is successful.

Comment: Finally some sensible answer :D + 1

Answer (score 1):

I assume that the quoted file is form.html...

```
<button name="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="yw1" type="submit">Tallenna</button>
```

you've defined submit without action property so it use the same page to submit form to... You must add action and direct it either to same file

```
<button name="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="yw1" type="submit" action='form.html?submitted=1'>Tallenna</button>
```

and onload to check for submitted parameter in query string and if exists to redirect or to direct it to a server site script (e.g. test.php)

```
<button name="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="yw1" type="submit" action='test.php'>Tallenna</button>
```

and redirect when work is done.

Answer (score 0):

when you submit form,it will goes at form.html,because you have add action in form to form.html

write following code in your form.html

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
    </script>

    <script>

$(function () { 

window.location.href="thankyou.html";
        }); 
    </script>
```

Comment: @hardbinger wants to thankyou.html page after submit..so,i gave above solution ...if he wants to go directly then have to change form action to thankyou.html.

Answer (score -1):

answer with adding `action` is wrong, because it sends data to thankyou.html instead form.html
so you may use js, it is very easy:
just add `onsubmit="window.location.href = 'thankyou.html'; return false;"` to form attributes

[example](http://jsfiddle.net/xq2Cu/10/)

Answer (score -1):

Just add a url at the action in the form tag. This would redirect to it. As shown below.

```
<form id="payTmForm" action="https://pguat.paytm.com/oltp-web/processTransaction" method="post">
</form>
```