# On condition fire all events, else fire none

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I am working on top of existing JavaScript (*that I cannot alter*) and need to check something on **submit**.

If my condition is true, no other submit handlers should be applied.

If my condition is false, all other submit handlers shall be applied.

What I have tried so far:

```
var form = jQuery('form'),
that = this,
events = $._data(form[0]).events['submit'];

form.off('submit');
form.on('submit', function (event) {
    if (that.myCondition()) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
        return false;
    } else {
       console.log('Call these: ', events);
    }
});
```

Now `events`is always empty at that point.

It is empty as soon as I call `form.off('submit')`and I didn't get it to work with deep cloning either.

Update:
In this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bkdm7fzt/1/) you see that both events are fired. I want one (*preferably one that i add LAST*) to be fired and prevent the other one from firing.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12252378/capturing-a-form-submit-with-jquery-and-submit I believe

Comment: wouldn't `return true;` in the `else{}` bit do the trick for you?

Comment: @Ted No, apparently not. The `return false;` doesn't do teh trick for me either and the simple `return true;` wouldn't the neccessarily deleted handlers.

Comment: Are there inline `onsubmit` or `onclick` attributes? Can modify those if needed. Also is form inserted by ajax ?

Comment: @mplungjan No it isn't. I know how to prevent a submit on a form. But the order in wich other submit handlers act is the problem for me.

Comment: @AndreschSerj Not certain interpret requirement correctly at _"I want one (preferably one that i add LAST) to be fired and prevent the other one from firing."_ ? At jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/bkdm7fzt/ `form.off('submit');` appear to have no effect as `form.on('submit', fn);` follows ? Both `submit` events have `true` for condition ? What is example of "condition" as it would be evaluated at `js` ?

Comment: @guest271314 In my update you see what i want.
One of the on submit handlers must be able to prevent the other.

http://jsfiddle.net/bkdm7fzt/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got your requirement correctly, you can try a nasty hack like

```
//the counter is just to demonstrate any condition
var counter = 0;
$('form').submit(function (e) {
    console.log('master handler form');
    //if counter is a multiple of 2 prevent other handlers
    if (++counter % 2 == 0) {
        //stop other submit handlers attached to the form
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        //stop propagation and default behavior
        return false;
    }
});

var form = jQuery('form'),
    events = $._data(form[0]).events['submit'];

var tmp = events.pop();
events.unshift(tmp);
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/0w8kww7y/)

Answer (score 1):

Try utilizing [`$.Callbacks("stopOnFalse")`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.callbacks/#supported-flags)

```
var callbacks = $.Callbacks("stopOnFalse");
// if `input.val().length === 0` `fn1` not called
var fn2 = function fn2(event) {
    // `this`:`form` element
    // console.log(this); 
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    console.log('1st submit called:', input.val().length);
    if (input.val().length === 0) {
        // `input.val().length === 0`
        // do stuff , do not do stuff ? here
        output1.html('Input needed!');
        // reset `output2` `html`
        output2.html("...");
        // return `false` to "stop" `callbacks` queue;
        // `fn1` not called
        return false;
    }
};
// if `input.val().length !== 0` , `fn1` called,
// else `fn1` not called
var fn1 = function fn1(event) {
    // do stuff 
    // call `event.preventDefault();` , here, if needed;
    // else call `output2.html('success!');` , submit form
    // event.preventDefault();
    console.log('2nd submit called:', input.val().length);
    output2.html('success!');
};
// add `fn2` , `fn1` to `callbacks` queue
callbacks.add(fn2, fn1);
// call both `fn2` , `fn1` if `input.val().length !== 0` ,
// else, do not call `fn1`
form.on('submit', function (event) {
    // `fire` `callbacks` `fn2` , `fn1` with context `this`:`form` ,
    // pass `event` as parameter to `fn2`, `fn1`
    callbacks.fireWith(this, [event])
});
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/bkdm7fzt/3/

Comment: Sadly i can not utilize that since, as i mentioned there are form handlers added that i have no influence on :-(