# JQuery: Post variable to the second file, and when the enter key pressed, the web will direct me to the first search result page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, search

I created an instant search similar to google search using JQuery.

Q1.
The post to search.php using search function searchq() then print out the returned result works fine, but the createq() function doesn't work at all, it didn't triggered when I using alert() to test, any ideas on how to fix it so the variable txt could be post to create_object.php (which has been post successfully to search.php).

Q2
I want to create a function that allow the user to direct to the first search result(which is anchored with an url) when the enter is pressed, any idea how to achieve this? I tried something but it messed up.

Note that I didn't include the connect to database function here. Coz I think the database username and password setting would be different to yours.So please create your own if you want to test it. The mysql is set with a table is called "objects", and it has one column named "name".

Thanks in advance!

```
 <html>
    <!-- google API reference -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- my own script for search function -->

    <center>
    <form method="POST">
        <input type="text" name="search" style="width:400px " placeholder="Search box" onkeyup="searchq();">
        <input type="submit" value=">>">
        <div id="output">
        </div>
    </form>
    </center>   

      <!-- instant search function -->
 <script type="text/javascript">

function searchq(){
        // get the value
            var txt = $("input").val();
            // post the value
            if(txt){
                $.post("search.php", {searchVal: txt}, function(result){
                    $("#search_output").html(result+"<div id=\"create\" onclick=\"creatq()\"><br>Not found above? Create.</div>");
                });
            }
            else{
                $("#search_output").html("");
            }


        };
function createq(){
    // allert for test purpose
    alert("hi");
    $.post( "create_object.php",{creatVal:txt} );

}

</script>
    </html>
```

PHP file (search.php)

```
 <?php
if(isset($_POST["searchVal"])){
    //get the search
    $search=$_POST["searchVal"];
    //sort the search
    $search=preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#i","",$search);
    //query the search
    echo "<br/>SELECT * from objects WHERE name LIKE '%$search%'<br/>";
    $query=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * from objects WHERE name LIKE '%$search%'") or die("could not search!");
    $count=mysqli_num_rows($query);
    //sort the result
    if($count==0){
        $output="there was no search result";
    }
    else{
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){

            $object_name=$row["name"];

            $output.="<div><a href='##'".$object_name."</a></div>";
        }
    }
    echo $output;
}
?>
```

php file (create_object.php)

```
 <?php
    if(isset($_POST["createVal"])){
        $name=$_POST["createVal"];
        var_dump($name);

    }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Two questions in one!

**Q1**: The problem appears to be a misspelling in the onclick function:

```
onclick=\"creatq()\"
```

should be

```
onclick=\"createq()\"
```

**Q2:** Pressing enter will submit the form, so you use the submit handler to catch the enter press then redirect:

```
$(function() { //shorthand document.ready function
    $('form ').on('submit', function(e) { //use on if jQuery 1.7+
        e.preventDefault();  //prevent form from submitting
        $url = $('#search_output div:first a').attr('href'); // find first link
        window.location.href = $url; // redirect
    });
});
```

(credit to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12252576) for most of the work)